# Does aio_write always write the whole buffer?

Tags: c, linux, posix, aio

I know that the POSIX `write` function can return successfully even though it didn't write the whole buffer (if interrupted by a signal).  You have to check for short writes and resume them.

But does `aio_write` have the same issue?  I don't think it does, but it's not mentioned in the documentation, and I can't find anything that states that it doesn't happen.

Comment: [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3697738/478288) says it does.

Comment: @chrisaycock, true, but it also says he's never actually used aio_*, so he could be mistaken.

Comment: The caller does not need to call `aio_write()` more then once to pass the whole buffer to `aoi_write()`. This however is not a guarantee that the whole buffer passed in will be written. A final call to `aio_error()` gives the result of the **whole** asyncronous I/O operation.

Answer (score 1):

The list of error codes on [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/aio_return.3.html) page doesn't include `EINTR`, which is the value in `errno` that means "please call again to do some more work". So, no you shouldn't need to call `aio_write` again for the same piece of data to be written.

This doesn't mean that you can rely on every write being completed. You still could, for example, get an partial write because the disk is full or some such. But you don't need to check for `EINTR` and "try again".

Comment: Was "this page" supposed to be a link?

Comment: Also, `write` only returns `EINTR` if the signal interrupts it before any data is written.  Otherwise, it returns success, but returns the number of bytes written as less than the number requested.

Comment: Fixed the link [my browser decided to restart, so I got a bit "lost" in what I was doing - should probably try another browser, but FF is usually pretty good].

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Please don't link to die pages. That is a bloated source of outdated, unofficial information, also full of ads. It just so happens it shows up first in google results for many people due to SEO (in which SO generally helps to boost its search ratings).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Excluding any case of error: Practical yes, theoratical not necessarily.

**Long answer**

From my experience the caller does not need to call `aio_write()` more then once to write the whole buffer using `aoi_write()`.

This however is not a guarantee that the whole buffer passed in really will be written. A final call to `aio_error()` gives the result of the **whole** asyncronous I/O operation, which could indicate an error.

Anyhow the documentation *does not explicitly excludes the case* that the final call to `aio_return()` returns *a value less then the amount of bytes to write out specified* in the original call to `aio_write()`, what indeed needs to be interpreted as that not the whole buffer would have been sent, in which case it would be necessary to call `aio_write()` again passing in what whould have been indicated as having been left over to write by the previous call.